# Replace $n$-th occurrence with number $n$

Tags: list-manipulation, function-construction, replacement, pattern-matching, string-manipulation

How can I replace $n$-th occurrence with number n for string/for list?

**For string :**

```
StringReplace["amkwajefiwaeah", "a" -> "A"]
"AmkwAjefiwAeAh"
```

But how can I get

`"1mkw2jefiw3e4h"` or
`"A1mkwA2jefiwA3eA4h"` ?

**For list :**

```
ReplaceAll[{a,m,k,w,a,j,e,f,i,w,a,e,a,h},a->A]
{A,m,k,w,A,j,e,f,i,w,A,e,A,h}
```

But how can I get

`{1,m,k,w,2,j,e,f,i,w,3,e,4,h}` or
`{{A,1},m,k,w,{A,2},j,e,f,i,w,{A,3},e,{A,4},h}` ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps this?:

```
Module[{cnt = 0}, 
 StringReplace["amkwajefiwaeah", "a" :> "A" <> ToString[++cnt]]]

(*  "A1mkwA2jefiwA3eA4h"  *)
```

And this?:

```
Module[{cnt = 0}, 
 ReplaceAll[{a, m, k, w, a, j, e, f, i, w, a, e, a, h}, 
  a :> {A, ++cnt}]]

(*  {{A, 1}, m, k, w, {A, 2}, j, e, f, i, w, {A, 3}, e, {A, 4}, h}  *)
```

Comment: Wow, such a noble solution! ++

Comment: An application of this method :  
`Fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grapes"};`  
`Module[{cnt = 0}, 
 StringReplace["amkwajefiwaeah", "a" :> Fruits[[++cnt]]]]`  
Then we get  
`"ApplemkwBananajefiwOrangeeGrapesh"`

Answer (score 8):

```
str = "amkwajefiwaeah"
pos = StringPosition[str, "a"]
```

> {{1, 1}, {5, 5}, {11, 11}, {13, 13}}

```
StringReplacePart[str, ToString /@ (Range[Length@pos]), pos]
```

> "1mkw2jefiw3e4h"

```
StringReplacePart[str, 
 "A" <> # & /@ ToString /@ (Range[Length@pos]), pos]
```

> "A1mkwA2jefiwA3eA4h"

---

For the example you mentioned:

```
fruits = {"Apple", "Banana", "Orange", "Grapes"};

StringReplacePart[str, fruits, pos]
```

> "ApplemkwBananajefiwOrangeeGrapesh"

Comment: Thanks for introducing `StringReplacePart` !

Answer (score 4):

```
cnt=1;
"amkwajefiwaeah" //
StringSplit[#,""]& //
Map[If[# == "a", ToString[cnt++], #]&] // 
StringJoin
```

> 1mkw2jefiw3e4h

```
cnt=1;
"amkwajefiwaeah" // 
StringSplit[#,""]& // 
Map[If[# == "a", "A" <> ToString[cnt++], #]&] // 
StringJoin
```

> A1mkwA2jefiwA3eA4h

Answer (score 4):

```
string = "amkwajefiwaeah";

list = Characters@string;

c = "a";
```

---

Get positions using `PositionIndex`:

```
p = List /@ Lookup[PositionIndex[list], c]
```

> {{1}, {5}, {11}, {13}}

The replacements:

```
rep = "" <> # & /@ 
      ToUpperCase@
      MapAt[ToString@#[[1]] &, 
      MapIndexed[List, Array["a" &, Length@p], {-1}], {All, 2}]
```

> {"A1", "A2", "A3", "A4"}

Finally, using `ReplacePart`:

```
StringJoin @ ReplacePart[list, Thread[p -> rep]] === string

(*True*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string = "amkwajefiwaeah";

list = Characters @ string;

c = "a";
```

Get positions

```
p = Flatten @ Position[list, c]
```

> {1, 5, 11, 13}

**For list**

```
a = SubsetMap[(ToString /@ Range @ Length @ p) &, list, p]
```

> {"1", "m", "k", "w", "2", "j", "e", "f", "i", "w", "3", "e", "4", "h"}

```
 b = ReplacePart[list, ReplacePart[p, i_ :> p[[i]] -> {ToUpperCase @ c, ToString @ i}]]
```

> {{"A", "1"}, "m", "k", "w", {"A", "2"}, "j", "e", "f", "i", "w", {"A",
> "3"}, "e", {"A", "4"}, "h"}

**For string**

```
StringJoin @@ a
```

> "1mkw2jefiw3e4h"

```
StringJoin @@ b
```

> "A1mkwA2jefiwA3eA4h"

Answer (score 2):

For list:

```
Function[{lst, el}, MapIndexed[Replace[#, el -> Count[lst[[;; #2[[1]]]], el]] &, 
    lst]][{a, m, k, w, a, j, e, f, i, w, a, e, a, h}, a]

(* {1, m, k, w, 2, j, e, f, i, w, 3, e, 4, h} *)
```

Or

```
Function[{lst, prefix, el}, MapIndexed[Replace[#, el -> {prefix,
   Count[lst[[;; #2[[1]]]], el]}] &, lst]][{a,m,k,w,a,j,e,f,i,w,a,e,a, h}, A, a]


(* {{A, 1}, m, k, w, {A, 2}, j, e, f, i, w, {A, 3}, e, {A, 4}, h} *)
```

Answer (score 2):

A very basic approach:

```
s = "amkwajefiwaeah";
e = Characters[s];
c = 0;
StringJoin[If[# == "a", c++; ToString[c], #] & /@ e]
```

yields: "1mkw2jefiw3e4h"